# Grunt.js: Loading task causes TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm trying to execute my grunt watch task but grunt throws an error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

It fails on my coffee script compiling task:

```
 coffee: 
     compile: 
         files: 'path/to/result.js': 'path/to/source.coffee'
```

Its really basic, so I cant see what is going wrong there. Any Idea what could be going on?

Here Is the stack trace produced after running `grunt watch -v`:

```
agconti :: ~/dev/my_project ‹master*› » grunt watch -v                                                                                                                3 ↵
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.coffee" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.coffee" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: object is not a function
>>     at Object.module.exports (/Users/admin/dev/fueled-boilerplate/Gruntfile.coffee:58:88)
>>     at loadTask (/Users/admin/dev/fueled-boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:318:10)
>>     at Task.task.init (/Users/admin/dev/fueled-boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:430:5)
>>     at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/admin/dev/fueled-boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:113:8)
>>     at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/admin/dev/fueled-boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:43:20)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Here is the entire Gruntfile.coffee:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->

# Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON 'package.json'

# CSS processing
        sass: 
            dist: 
                options: 
                    style: 'expanded'
                files: 
                    'assets/build/css/compiled/screen.css' : 'assets/css/screen.scss'

        compass: 
            options: 
                sassDir: 'assets/css/'
                cssDir: 'assets/build/css/compiled/'
                imagesDir: 'assets/images/'
                javascriptsDir: 'assets/build/js/'
                outputStyle: 'expanded'

            dist:""
            server: 
                options: 
                    debugInfo: true

        autoprefixer: 
            options: 
                browsers: ['last 2 version']

            multiple_files:
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                src: 'assets/build/css/compiled/screen.css'
                dest: 'assets/build/css/prefixed/'

        modernizr: 
            "devFile": "assets/js/modernizr/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"
            "outputFile": "assets/build/js/modernizr-custom.js"

        cssmin: 
            combine: 
                files:'assets/build/css/screen.min.css': ['assets/build/css/prefixed/screen.css']

# JavaScript Processing
        coffee: 
            compile: 
                files: 'path/to/result.js': 'path/to/source.coffee' 

        jshint: 
            beforeconcat: ['assets/js/*.js']

        concat: 
            dist: 
                src: [
                    'assets/js/vendor/*.js'
                    'assets/js/*.js']
                dest: 'assets/build/js/main.js'

        uglify: 
            build: 
                src: 'assets/build/js/main.js',
                dest: 'assets/build/main.min.js'

# Image Processing
        imagemin: 
            dynamic: 
                files: [
                    expand: true
                    cwd: "assets/images/"
                    src: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg}']
                    dest: "assets/images/"
                    ]

# Watch Task
        watch: 
            options:
                livereload: 
                    port: 9000 # Allows you to specify port incase you want to run multiple projects as once.
                    #Allows you to connect an Https server and still have livereload 
                    key: grunt.file.read 'path/to/ssl.key'
                    cert: grunt.file.read 'path/to/ssl.crt'
                    #you can pass in any other options you'd like to the https server, as listed here: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener
            scripts: 
                files: 'assets/js/*/js'
                tasks: ['concat', 'uglify', 'jshint']
                options: 
                    spawn: false

            html: 
                files: ['*.html', '**/*.html']
                tasks: []
                options: 
                    spawn: false


            compass: 
                files: ['assets/css/*.scss', 'assets/css/**/*.scss']
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer', 'cssmin', 'clean']

            images: 
                files: ['assets/images/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}', 'assets/images/*.{png,gif,jpg}']
                tasks: ['imagemin']
                options: 
                    spawn: false

# Connect Task
        connect: 
            server: 
                options: 
                    port: 8000
                    base: './'

# Clean Task
        clean: ['assets/build/css/prefixed/', 'assets/build/css/compiled/']


# Load dependencies
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)

# Define Tasks
    grunt.registerTask 'default', [
                                    'concat' 
                                    'uglify' 
                                    'sass' 
                                    'imagemin'
                                ]

    grunt.registerTask 'dev', [
                                'connect' 
                                'modernizr' 
                                'watch'
                            ]
```

Load grunt tasks file:

```
'use strict';
var globule = require('globule');
var findup = require('findup-sync');
var path = require('path');

function arrayify(el) {
    return Array.isArray(el) ? el : [el];
}

module.exports = function (grunt, options) {
    options = options || {};

    var pattern = arrayify(options.pattern || ['grunt-*']);
    var config = options.config || findup('package.json');
    var scope = arrayify(options.scope || ['dependencies', 'devDependencies', 'peerDependencies']);

    if (typeof config === 'string') {
        config = require(path.resolve(config));
    }

    pattern.push('!grunt', '!grunt-cli');

    var names = scope.reduce(function (result, prop) {
        return result.concat(Object.keys(config[prop] || {}));
    }, []);

    globule.match(pattern, names).forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fueled-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-modernizr": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `load-grunt-tasks` file?

Comment: show your `package.json`

Comment: @IlanFrumer included above.

Comment: @dcodesmith included above

Comment: @dcodesmith also tried with `require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks)` incase it was the load-grunt-tasks file, but same result

Comment: I installed everything and it works fine. run `grunt --version` , `coffee -v` please.

Comment: What happens if you actually include all the load the grunt files as normal and not with you custom scripts?

Comment: @IlanFrumer grunt version yeilds: `grunt-cli v0.1.11
grunt v0.4.2` and coffee -v yeilds: `CoffeeScript version 1.6.3`

Comment: Try to comment out the watch tasks. BTW, Your watch task doesn't watch the coffee task so it's another task.

Comment: i believe its all happening before the watch task is even being called. for example if I call `grunt coffee` i get the same result

Comment: @dcodesmith I get a weird parse error: `Unexpected '.'` I've loaded the tasks the traditional way without this error occurring before.

Comment: Ok, so obviously that might be the problem. Have you managed to tract it down?

Comment: @dcodesmith not yet, I've examined a previous grunt file using that config and I cant find a difference between them. Strangely though IllanFrumer rant this file and had no issues. so I cant see what could be wrong with my local machine

Comment: @IlanFrumer you installed it as is and everything ran fine?

Comment: @dcodesmith I just pulled it down from the SO post and everything ran fine. Spooky, but perhaps there were trailing special characters or spaces with tabs or something. either way thanks for the help. I wish I could give you rep. Illan, I gave your answer +1 for helping me get here.

Comment: @agconti I use [EditorConfig](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/EditorConfig) to force 2 space indentation ( coffee / jade / python / sass ). Also I use [Java​Script & Coffeescript Build Systems](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JavaScript%20%26%20Coffeescript%20Build%20Systems) to compile coffee-script and see If something went wrong.

Comment: @IlanFrumer thats a nice package. thanks for writing it!

Answer (score 9):

#### Try to make a clean installation of npm modules:

`rm -rf node_modules &&  npm cache clean && npm install`

Comment: great idea, same issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by replacing spaces for tabs in the code identation (the dots below).

```
 coffee: 
 ....compile: 
 ........files: 'path/to/result.js': 'path/to/source.coffee'
```